# Creating automatic crud grid and actions with Sylius (Symfony bundle)

Tags: grid, symfony, crud, sylius

I tried to use Sylius Grid system to make my articles management easy.
So, I followed the [Sylius doc](http://docs.sylius.org/en/latest/bundles/SyliusGridBundle/your_first_grid.html) and I see the grid with my articles displayed. Then I've added action buttons but when I want to use them, I have an error (only for edit and create. Delete works well): `Class "form" is not configured for resource "blog.article".`

I understand that it can't find any FormClass to render my Article, but there is not this information in the doc, and I think I saw on a doc (I don't remember which) that the form is rendered automatically according to the Entity.

Here is my code :

Declaration of the resource :

```
sylius_resource:
    resources:
        blog.article:
            driver: doctrine/orm
            classes:
                model: BlogBundle\Entity\Article
```

The grid config :

```
sylius_grid:
    grids:
        blog_admin_article:
            driver:
                name: doctrine/orm
                options:
                    class: BlogBundle\Entity\Article
            sorting:
                date: asc
            fields:
                titre:
                    type: string
                    label: sylius.ui.title
                    sortable: ~
                date:
                    type: datetime
                    label: sylius.ui.date
                    sortable: ~
                resume:
                    type: string
                    label: sylius.ui.resume
                    sortable: ~
            filters:
                search:
                    type: string
                    label: sylius.ui.search
                    options:
                        fields: [titre, resume ]
            actions:
                main:
                    create:
                        type: create
                        label: sylius.ui.create
                item:
                    update:
                        type: update
                    delete:
                        type: delete
                    show:
                        type: show
```

The route :

```
blog_admin_article:
    resource: |
        alias: blog.article
        section: admin
        templates: SyliusAdminBundle:Crud
        except: ['show']
        redirect: update
        grid: blog_admin_article
        vars:
            all:
                subheader: blog.ui.articles.subtitle 
            index:
                icon: 'newspaper icon'
    type: sylius.resource
```

Does anyone know what is the problem  ?

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the autogeneration of forms was disabled in the beta1, there are 2 ways to solve your problem:

1. Create and declare your own form type [like here in the docs](http://docs.sylius.org/en/latest/bundles/SyliusResourceBundle/forms.html) (ArticleType).
2. Use `dev-master` branch of Sylius instead of beta1, where the autogeneration is back.

Comment: Thanks CoderMaggie, I will try this. 
How can I know there is newer version ? I saw on the composer doc there is a "outdated" option, but it does not work with my composer...

Comment: Changing "sylius/sylius": "^1.0@beta" to "sylius/sylius": "dev-master", I have an error when I want to show the articles at the url "/articles" which worked before : `"Unable to generate a URL for the named route "blog_admin_article_show" as such route does not exist."`

Comment: Ok, it was the `show:
                        type: show` that was a problem in my grid config.

Comment: Glad you've managed to fix it. :) When it come to releases, you have to follow Sylius (blog, twitter, github, slack, whatever you want).